# Magento2: Lifetime sales not getting updated on dashboard due to invoice issue

Tags: magento2.4, dashboard

I'm using a payment method of my country. When somebody realice an order in my website, and the payment is successfully, the order is changed to status `complete`.

The problem is, I can't do "invoice", and the `lifetime sales` statistics in the dashboard is not updated. (I guess it is because the invoice doesn't exists in that order)

Exists an easy way to show the total for `complete` orders and not by `invoices`?

Thanks